# remove tab bar blurred effect

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

Is there any away to remove tab bar blurred effect
I set background image and it looks like the first picture.
If I make it transparent, you can see the table through it like the second picture.
I want to make it like the third picture

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can make it *transparent* using 
the `barTintColor` property.

```
nameOfTabBar.barTintColor = .clear
```

This property is incharge of the tint *color* to apply to the tab bar background.

You can find more information on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar

Comment: it becomes even worse - setting to "clear" color makes it dark gray